# Javascript IF execution error

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

The following is a part of my code :

```
$.post("checkbuddy.php",function(data){
  if(data!="a"){
    $("#Layer15").css({ visibility: 'visible'});
    $("#Layer10").css({ visibility: 'visible'});
    $("#Layer10").html(data);
  }
});
```

The condition `if(data!="a")` doesn't seem to be working, as checkbuddy.php returns `"a"`. And what happens is that the HTML of Layer10 changes to `"a"`, and thus the text shown is `"a"`. This shouldn't be happening should it?

Comment: What does `alert(data)` and `alert(typeof data)` say?

Comment: I guess `data == "a\n"`.

Comment: what does `alert(data.length)` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra space after the closing `?>` tag or before the `<?php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace may well be the problem. Use jQuery's **[`.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** function:

```
$.post("checkbuddy.php",function(data){
    if($.trim(data) !="a"){
        $("#Layer15").show();
        $("#Layer10").show();
        $("#Layer10").html(data);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the whitespace, as said in the other answers, but it can also be the MIME type. If checkbuddy.php is not returning a text/html or text/plain MIME type and is instead text/xml, jQuery might be converting it into an object of some sort, which would mess up the comparison.